# Site Collection admin getting error 'Sorry, this item hasn't been shared with you.'

Tags: 2013, authentication, access, denied

I am getting this new error in chrome. I am logged into Windows with a Site Collection Administrator. I tried clearing the browser cache and passwords but no luck. This doesn't happen in IE or Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: what authentication method is being used? in IE / Firefox did they ask for credentials?

Comment: Yes they both asked for credentials. Chrome doesn't so I assume it's trying to passthrough my Windows creds. The web app is using default Claims Based Authentication

Comment: try this one after the site collection url 
/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true then enter the credentials for site collection admin

Comment: Awesome..Fixed it. Can you put that in an answer please!

Comment: good to know, i just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion, looks like Chrome is getting the windows credentials and in SharePoint 2013, we don't have the **"sign in with different user"** options. that is the reason you getting the above error.

But still you can login in with different user with direclty browsing this way,

```
http://www.sitecolectiourl.com/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true
```

Comment: Yeah. Not sure if this was the cause, but my account was locked out and somehow Chrome refuse to believe it was unlocked. Regardless, this forces a sign in again which is very useful

Comment: just for infromation...are you login on the PC with the same account as the admin account on Site collection

Comment: Not logged in with the main admin account, but my personal one is also site collection admin